# React using Axios to populate a list

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm stuck trying to extract user name from the object using Axios:  anyone available to help ?  Thanks

`[{"id":4,"username":"user1","password":"$2a$14$0/s7FciPuSW.XBtOSG5jUO1iUQwMFWqeboTaPBuFuMFlifI76G0ua","locked":0,"created_at":"2018-08-06 22:08:03"},{"id":5,"username":"user2","password":"$2a$14$QdRO/.mWqUbJV66HciCw3OXIXDKeZH7mcdUBdS9zUaiZNi20bjMi6","locked":0,"created_at":"2018-08-06 22:09:38"},{"id":6,"username":"user3","password":"$2a$14$pMGLWvsDQqM3rll6OX2uE.UgDomGXiFJ8Szz0PyYgr7DQQse6le7u","locked":0,"created_at":"2018-08-06 22:09:51"},{"id":7,"username":"user9","password":"$2a$14$fVJkOyCY992nKjiiJY/aeuAXlgKXHz34cLPNYGFuXMBz4UqPUF3Pu","locked":0,"created_at":"2018-08-07 23:39:57"}]`

Comment: Let me know if you like me to post my code

Comment: Obviously... :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple js array so you should be able to do the following.

`const users = array.map(e => e.username);`

Which would take your array of items and map it into an array of usernames.

Comment: Thanks Adam ... I had a typo in a variable name (fat finger). Resolved and vote + 1